# Windows installer package throwing error when I try running it from file server

Tags: windows, msi

Right now I am trying to use PDQ deploy to push out an update (20.2.40) for a software called Bluebeam, if you haven't heard of it, it's essentially a PDF editor.

I have also tried running this MSI installer without PDQ, when I run it on my computer from my C drive it works perfect and opens up a prompt to start the installation but when I run it from our shared server it throws me an error saying, "This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package."

When I try pushing it to my computer through PDQ I use this command ->

```
START /WAIT msiexec.exe /i "\\SERVERNAME\Departments\Technologies\Installs\Bluebeam Revu\MSIBluebeamRevu20.2.40x64\BluebeamOCR x64 20.msi" /qn && msiexec.exe /i "\\SERVERNAME\Departments\Technologies\Installs\Bluebeam Revu\MSIBluebeamRevu20.2.40x64\Bluebeam Revu x64 20.msi" TRANSFORMS="\\SERVERNAME\Departments\Technologies\Installs\Bluebeam Revu\MSIBluebeamRevu20.2.40x64\Bluebeam Revu x64 20.mst"
```

This command comes from a built in part of the bluebeam software called the "configuration editor" and is used to create and edit commands for deployments. When the command is finished running on my computer, PDQ tells me that my computer return an error code 1620 and that it failed.

Why am I getting this error only when I try to run this installer from my shared server? I have tried re-downloading the MSI package but that didn't help. I thought that maybe after I downloaded it that when I copied the files onto my server it might have dropped data making the MSI corrupt and that's why I was getting the error; however, all the files in the MSI package on my server are the same size as those on my C drive.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is the target computer able to access the network share? Try opening ```\\SERVERNAME\Departments\Technologies\Installs\Bluebeam Revu\MSIBluebeamRevu20.2.40x64\``` on the computer you are trying to push the command on and see if it's able to access the fie.

Comment: Yeah I'm pushing it onto my own computer and I can access all the files in the MSI package

Comment: To me, that narrows it down to either network file security or the user the command is running as doesn't have access to the network share, which I would try to pin down first. Do you know if the remote command is running as ```SYSTEM```?

Comment: @JoshZhang yeah it is running as SYSTEM. I thought it might have something to do with my permissions on our servers. I am an intern at this company and while I do have access to a lot of our network I don't have access to do everything

Comment: Your company could have a designated service account to run the command remotely that has access to the network share, or if you're the one executing it you could always just have the installer run as your user though I wouldn't recommend that per se.